# Create local wifi network to connect my tablet with RPI

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-3

I want to create local wifi network using RPI so that my Android tabled can connect to RPI using wifi to exchange files with RPI (sftp). Previously I tried to use simple mtp but somehow it does not work on RPI (programs just does not handle any of my device correctly) and bluetooth never works on linux. Thus my next option is to use wifi. I tried to google for "linux local wifi network" but haven't found anything useful. Please run me through necessary commands/config or at least provide some phrases that would yield usable result in google.

Comment: Which Pi do you have (would be better add to a tag to the question)? the instructions might be slightly different (wrt drivers/firmware) depending on whether you have a onboard wifi (Pi3) or an external wifi adapter. I usually follow the instructions [here](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point.pdf) to setup the PI as an access point.

Comment: @ShreyasMurali I have rpi3